# Operator matrix element Feynman diagrams

Tags: tikz-feynman, feynman, feynmf, feynmp, feynmp-auto

I am trying to draw the following cutted diagram
[image]

but I don't know how to do it.

I am using feynmf for the Feynman diagrams for my thesis since tikz-feynman requires lualatex and it gives enormous compiling times.

On a more general note, I would like to know these Wick contraction diagrams are usually made

[image]

As far as I know, there isn't any specific package to do them beside tikz which is a bit cumbersome and I really would like to avoid it!

Comment: My regards from Sicily :-)...Please can I know where you have taken the first image? Where have you taken the images type1,2,3,4? From an old book?

Comment: @Sebastiano Ciao! The first diagram I draw it myself with a tablet. The others come from a [recent work on $\epsilon^\prime/\epsilon$](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.09440), but they are well known in the literature and can be found in many other places. These were the ones I had at hand at the moment!

Comment: I hope I am not mistaken but I have seen the pdf. Whoever wrote the article also uses typical Word fonts (i.e. Symbol). It may be that the article is not written in LaTeX. Also, the images are inserted externally and may not be created with a specific package. I have some doubt, but I think they were created with a graphics program.  Grazie very very much. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes, I would imagine that the images are possibly made externally to latex. But if we take, for example, the diagrams in pages 51/52 of [this lectures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.00798) they seem to be directly done in latex!

Comment: @Sebastiano The paper is (badly) written in TeX (you can download the source) but the figures are external, generated by cairo (maybe gnuplot? the arrow heads look familiar...).

Comment: @DavideMorgante For example if you go to page 24/86 or 32/86 to the 100 % the images are done with tikz-feynmann. To the page 55/86 . I have not understood the pages 51 and 52. In the page 51 there is not any image. To the page 52 the image is external. But I am able to drawing the graphs to the page 55/86 quickly :-)

Comment: @campa Yes yes it is true. I have download the .pdf file. Can be that the document is written in word-office and someone have download the .ttf font of CM.

Comment: @Quiver, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with `tikz`.

The code below shows your 4 types, and your sketch at the end. With the following it's easy to create other diagrams of similar complexity, step-by-step, in a kind of modular way:

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

% ~~~ PROCEDURE ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%   0. use or include the `\tikzset` statement below
%   1. put coordinates
%   2. put nodes with labels, using the text styles tl, tr
%   3. draw one path
%   3a. use normal `--` first
%   3b. replace as needed, e.g. by `to [bend left]` etc.
%   4. turn `\draw` into `\draw[postaction={decorate}]`
%   5. copy decoration style and adjust the `mark=at position` statements as needed


\tikzset{
    mat/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=2pt},% matrix element
    tl/.style={xshift=-2.5mm},%              shift text to left
    tr/.style={xshift= 2.5mm},%              shift text to right
    lp/.style={min distance=12mm},%          loop style
}
```

Kindly recognize that the single path sometimes skips drawing a line.

And yes, you can still improve on the *pi-banana* ;-)

[image: results]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

% ~~~ PROCEDURE ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%   0. use or include the `\tikzset` statement below
%   1. put coordinates
%   2. put nodes with labels, using the text styles tl, tr
%   3. draw one path
%   3a. use normal `--` first
%   3b. replace as needed, e.g. by `to [bend left]` etc.
%   4. turn `\draw` into `\draw[postaction={decorate}]`
%   5. copy decoration style and adjust the `mark=at position` statements as needed


\tikzset{
    mat/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=2pt},% matrix element
    tl/.style={xshift=-2.5mm},%              shift text to left
    tr/.style={xshift= 2.5mm},%              shift text to right
    lp/.style={min distance=12mm},%          loop style
}

\begin{document}
 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \begin{tikzpicture}%                  type 1
    [decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.1  with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.4 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.9 with {\arrow{stealth}},
    }]
    \coordinate (K)  at (  0,0);
    \coordinate (P1) at ( 20:4);
    \coordinate (P2) at (-10:4);
    \coordinate (M)  at ( 10:2);    
    
    \node[tl]            at (K)     {$K$};
    \node[tr,yshift=1mm] at (P1)    {$\pi$};
    \node[tr]            at (P2)    {$\pi$};
    \node[mat]           at (M)     {}; 
    
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] 
        (K) to [bend left] (M) 
            to [bend left] (P1) to [bend left] (M)
            to [bend right] (P2) to [bend left] (K);
  \end{tikzpicture}
 
 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \begin{tikzpicture}%                  type 2
    [decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.1 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.33 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.7 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.9 with {\arrow{stealth}},
    }]
    \coordinate (K)  at (0,0);
    \coordinate (P1) at ( 10:2);
    \coordinate (P2) at (-10:2);
    \coordinate (M)  at (0:1);  
    
    \node[tl] at (K)  {$K$};
    \node[tr] at (P1) {$\pi$};
    \node[tr] at (P2) {$\pi$};
    \node[mat] at (M) {};   
    
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (K) to [bend left] (M) to [bend right] (P2) to [bend left] (P1) to [bend right] (M) to [bend left] (K);
  \end{tikzpicture}
 
 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \begin{tikzpicture}%                  type 3
    [decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.1 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.24 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.4 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.55 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.8 with {\arrow{stealth}},
    }]
    \coordinate (K)         at (  0,0);
    \coordinate (P1)        at ( 20:4);
    \coordinate (P2)        at (-10:4);
    \coordinate (M)         at ( 10:2);
        
    \node[tl] at (K)        {$K$};
    \node[tr] at (P1)       {$\pi$};
    \node[tr] at (P2)       {$\pi$};
    \node[mat] at (M)       {}; 
    
    % loop WAS missing
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] 
        (K) to [bend left] (M) 
            to [out=-20,in=-150,lp] (M)
            to [bend left] (P1) to [bend right] (P2) to [bend left] (K);
  \end{tikzpicture}
 
 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \begin{tikzpicture}%                  type 4
    [decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.1 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.36 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.53 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.73 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.89 with {\arrow{stealth}},
    }]
    \coordinate (K)  at (0,0);
    \coordinate (P1) at ( 10:4);
    \coordinate (P2) at (-10:4);
    \coordinate (M)  at ( 0:2); 
  
    \node[tl] at (K)        {$K$};
    \node[tr] at (P1)       {$\pi$};
    \node[tr] at (P2)       {$\pi$};
    \node[mat] at (M)   {};     
    
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] 
            (K) to [bend left] (M) 
                to [out=-20,in=20,lp] (M)
                to [bend left] (K) 
            (P1) to [bend right] (P2) to [out=180,in=180] (P1);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  % ~~~ sketch ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.2 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.45 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.77 with {\arrow{stealth}},
        mark=at position 0.9 with {\arrow{stealth}},
    }]
    \coordinate (K) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (P0) at (3,0);
    \coordinate (Pp) at (3,2);
    \coordinate (H)  at (30:2.5);

    \node[tl] at (K)    {$K^+$};
    \node[tr] at (P0)   {$\pi^0$};
    \node[tr,yshift=2mm] at (Pp)    {$\pi^+$};
    
    \draw[postaction={decorate}]  
            (K) to [bend left] (P0) 
                to [bend left] (K)
            (H) to [bend left] (Pp) to [bend left] (H);
    
    \draw[dashed] (1.5,.5) to [bend left] (H);
    
    \draw[red,line width=1.5pt] (.9,1.0) to [bend left] (2.5,.6);
    
  \end{tikzpicture}    
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually I sort of solved the problem at the time by using an external program at the end. It was for my thesis and I didn't have a lot of time.